# Is there a difference in performance between accessing properties of static and non-static class?

Tags: c#, static-classes

I'm just wondering whether there is any difference in performance for accessing properties of a static instead of non-static class?

Let's say I have to classes

```
private class Book1
{
   public const EventEnum Name = "Something";
}

private static class Book2
{
   public const EventEnum Name = "Something";
}
```

Now, if I want to access them in the following way

```
var book1Name = Book1.Name;
var book2Name = Book2.Name;
```

is there an difference in performance?
Is there any difference at all?

Thanks

Comment: Don't try to learn millions of "performance rules" and then rigidly apply them. The best way to write good code is to first write *readable*, clearly *correct* code. Whilst doing that, also create performance *goals*. Once you've done that, **measure** your performance, and then target your efforts where your tools tell you you have a performance *issue*.

Comment: [MeasureIt](https://measureitdotnet.codeplex.com/documentation)

Comment: var book1Name = Book1.Name; Does that work if it's not static?

Comment: Those aren't properties, they're constants. And you can't mark a constant `static`, so this doesn't compile. Of course, that's incidental to your question, to which the answer is "you will have a very hard time ever finding an actual scenario where the answer to this is the least bit relevant, and if you do you will not get around measuring actual code anyway". See also [Eric Lippert's obligatory remarks on this](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/).

Comment: _"We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil."_

Comment: What if I don't mark these constants static, just the class itself?

Comment: A constant cannot be marked as static, it *is* static

Comment: I vote for reopening. The question is **not** a duplicate. OP asks the difference between static members of a non-static and a static class. The linked duplicate refers to static vs non-static **members**. The answer however should be the same

Comment: The OP is asking about properties, though mentioning constants. For *constants* at least, the answer is clear: there is zero difference because they're constants. All constants are inlined. For properties, the question is a duplicate because property getters are methods.

Comment: The code is using `const`, this will not behave the way you're expecting. The code will compile to exactly the same code which is basically just `var book1Name = "Something";` in both cases.

Comment: If the class is private, how does one access the properties?